# android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC Permission Declaration for Android API 34

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am working on upgrading my Unity-based mobile application to target Android API 34 for publishing on Google Play Console. However, I am facing an issue where Google Play Console is requesting a declaration for the android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC permission. I am using Unity version 2022.3.16f and having difficulty identifying where in my project this permission is being used.

My question is: How can I determine where in my Unity project I am using the android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC permission? If I am not using it, how can I remove it? If I am using it, is there a way to identify where for accurate declaration on Google Play Console?

Thank you for your attention!

If I use something related to this permission in my application, I want to declare it to the console. I want to remove this permission if I'm not using it.

I think a video is required to declare it correctly. how can i make true video for it?

Answer (score -1):

If you change the settings this way, it will not give a warning.

Project Setting/Player/Other Setting/Target API Level/API Level 33

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If Android is complaining about it, then you must necessarily be using it somewhere.

Given [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC) for that permission, it seems that you must be calling `startForeground` with type "dataSync" somewhere in your code, specifically in a Service.

Look for that line of code (`startForeground`) and if it's there, double-check that you are indeed using the "dataSync" type.

At the end of the day, I recommend you find the `AndroidManifest.xml` file -- whether you're generating it directly thru Unity, or using the Android one -- and add that permission as to make Google happy.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC"/>
```